# Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely in modal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When i enter wrong password or email in my modal form to login my MVC website actually my viewbag does not work in my code in controller :

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public  ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Encode = Encryption.EncodePasswordMd5(login.Password);
            var logined = db.Members.Where(s => s.EmailAddress == login.EmailAddress && s.Password == Encode).FirstOrDefault();
            if (logined != null)
            {     //todo: redircet to admin panel
                if (logined.Role==Role.admin)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(logined.Id.ToString(), login.KeepMe);
                    return RedirectToAction("panel", "Admin");
                }
                  //todo: redircet to user panel
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(logined.Id.ToString(), login.KeepMe);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ViewBag.Error = "wrong email or password";
            return View();
        }

        return View(login);
    }
```

This is my bootstrap modal in my Layout:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="bodymodal">
            @Html.Action("Login","Account")
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: MD5 hashing isn't your best bet for storing away passwords.

Comment: but better than save without hashing !my problem not this!

Comment: Your problem *now* is not this - it will be later on, when you've forgotten that you've done this, and have to defend the fact in front of a group of people who ask why their credentials were stolen.

Comment: OK .what the best hashing for storing away passwords?

Comment: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/ says, "There are currently three algorithms which are safe to use: PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt"

Comment: thanks bro! it,s so help ful

Answer (score 1):

Login action method is returning a view which is including the Login action method. Basically, you are calling yourself over and over.

You probably just need to be including a different Action method: `@Html.Action("LoginForm","Account")`